# Easy one: does ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED return something like a "no devices found"?

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

as someone's who's just starting to get into Android/Java programming, I've read the docs at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED and i'm trying to figure out what whether I would only get ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED when the bluetooth 12 second scan is completed, and it comes back WITH NO DEVICES, or, does it return ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED every time it scans, and it has some sort of return code that I don't see in the docs?

The scenario is: I'm building a broadcast receiver that would listen in to BT, and if it is turned on,  starts discovery and ends discovery AND finds nothing, I wanna turn off BT.

If it does return codes, I would love a link/the codes themselves.

Thanks for reading and helping out!

Comment: If a broadcast has any further information attached, then the docs usually state that. e.g. "This intent will have 3 extras: EXTRA_X, .."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED tells you that discovery has finished, no more or less.

There is a separate Intent, ACTION_FOUND, that is sent when a device is discovered.

To accomplish your desired functionality, you want to check in your broadcast receiver

```
intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
```

If an intent is received such that this evaluates to true, then you have discovered a BluetoothDevice. If you want to do processing on that device, you can access it via

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

Edit: If you only want to know that no devices were found, you can just set a flag in the ACTION_FOUND-handling code. If the flag isn't set, then no devices were found.

EDIT2: The process of Bluetooth Device discovery will send out this sequence of intents:

1 ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED
0 or more ACTION_FOUND
1 ACTION_DISCOVERY_ENDED

Comment: ok, so, if I understand you correctly, set a receiver to listen to ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED. Once I get that, I can check on ACTION_FOUND. If the extra field EXTRA_DEVICE is false, then I know that no devices were found. Correct? thanks for the quick answer, btw...

Comment: or do I listen to ACTION_FOUND, and that will return false if it finds nothing, forgoing the ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED?

Comment: sorry, I was a bit unclear: the ACTION_FOUND is an intent that is broadcast (your receiver also listens for ACTION_FOUND) whenever a device is found during discovery. So, if your broadcast receiver gets an ACTION_FOUND any time during discovery, then you know that a device was found. On the other hand, if ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED occurs after you start discovering, and there have been no ACTION_FOUND intents, then there were no devices found.

Comment: so, logically, I only get ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED when bluetooth went through it's process of looking for a device, and couldn't find one - if it CAN find one, it will send out the ACTION_FOUND instead.... did I get that right?

Comment: just about - you will only get one ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED, when the process of searching ends. However, this will happen whether a device has been found or not. You will get an ACTION_FOUND each time a remote device is discovered; this could be 0, 1, or more times. With each ACTION_FOUND intent is an Extra, which contains info on the remote device (hardware address, name). It's a bit unintuitive for your application, I think, but in general there's some logic to it. I edited my answer to clear it up a bit

Comment: I almost understand - this is the line that's confusing to me: " You will get an ACTION_FOUND each time a remote device is discovered; this could be 0, 1, or more times." how can i discover something 0 times? or, to put it more clearly, will i get the ACTION_FOUND intent, even if nothing was found, and if so, how do i know that nothing was found? is it null? false? thanks for helping out!!

Comment: You can get multiple ACTION_FOUNDs if you discover multiple different devices. You will not the get ACTION_FOUND if no devices were found - the lack of ACTION_FOUND intents signifies that no devices were found. Glad to help! I spent lots of time working through the Android BT APIs, and I know how tricky they are

Comment: one last question about your answer - you said set a flag - the only way i know to do this through sharedPreferences. is there a better way?

Comment: ah I just meant have some instance variable that you set to False when you start discovery, and then set it to True when you find a device

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9027/discussion-between-raingod-and-mfrankli)